# "... эту, довольно простую в исполнении, технику". Верно ли расставлены запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

"Поэтому эту, довольно простую в исполнении, технику дыхания можно порекомендовать многим современным людям".

Comment: Юлия, точку ставят после закрывающих кавычек.

Answer (score 3):

А зачем они нам? Без них свободнее берешь дыхание при чтении вслух...

И правило подсказывает то же:

> Если определительный оборот, стоящий после указательного местоимения,
>   тесно примыкает к нему и не имеет значения уточнения, то он не
>   отделяется запятой от этого местоимения.

**[источник](http://www.xliby.ru/jazykoznanie/spravochnik_po_russkomu_jazyku_punktuacija/p6.php)**

Comment: Правильно! Ещё мне кажется, что нужно было бы обособление только в том случае, если бы "эта" означало ту, о которой уже было сказано что-то, технику.

Answer (score 1):

Поэтому эту, **довольно простую в исполнени**и, технику дыхания можно порекомендовать многим современным людям.

По Розенталю возможны оба варианта (с уточнением и без уточнения).  В то же время следует учитывать структуру предложения и распространенность определения (здесь используются согласованное и несогласованное виды определений, местоимение, определительный оборот). Как мне кажется, с обособлением предложение **легче читается**, да и автор имее право **подчеркнуть** простоту техники.

Основное правило:

Определительный оборот, стоящий после определительного, указательного или притяжательного местоимения, тесно примыкает к нему и запятой не отделяется: Даша ждала всего, но только не **этой покорно склонённой** головы (А. Т.);

Дополнение

Уточняющие определения могут конкретизировать общее значение местоимений этот, тот, такой, каждый, один (в значении местоимения) и т. п.

Хотелось отличиться перед **этим, дорогим для меня**, человеком (М. Г.); Затем удивила Дашу «доморощенность» всего **этого, так нашумевшего,** дерзновения.

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать запятые - то верно (хотя просится другое выделение оценки, но нынешнее поколение молодняка из всей пунктуации знает только запятые, так что сойдет).

Без запятых будет тоже не менее верно.